# How to use tinymce_advance plugin?

Tags: php

I want to use Tinymce_advance plugin in my website.I downloaded the file and placed in my local server where my project files exist.Now how can I use this plugin?

Comment: what does `readme` says?

Answer (score 1):

Please read their documentation:
http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Advanced

Add the script reference to TinyMce in the header of the page, and then start by adding the snipplet from the url above within your `<body>` to begin with.

Comment: thx.. :) but I am asking about Tinymce_advance...

Comment: @JewelSarkar not sure what you are referring to. Are you referring to the wordpress plugin? http://wordpress.org/plugins/tinymce-advanced/

Comment: I am not using wordpress, Joomla etc. I am just trying to use the advance tinymce editor in my php page. I downloaded Tinymce 4.0.x and placed it a same folder in the local server where my project exits. But I am getting a classic editor which I don't want..So it will be very helpful if you suggest me something regarding this..thank you # Henkealg

Answer (score 1):

> Place inside the  of your HTML

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="tinymce.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
tinymce.init
({
    //go to  coding!

 });
</script>
```

**Update**

**i think you are looking for styles !**

See this [fiddle.tinymce](http://fiddle.tinymce.com/2mdaab/1)

Read on : [Configuration Style_formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration3x%3astyle_formats)

Read a Sample Here : [TinyMCE Styles](http://www.tinymce.com/forum/viewtopic.php?id=10974)

See an Example Here :[custom_formats](http://www.tinymce.com/tryit/custom_formats.php)

Also Read : 
[Helping Hands](http://alisothegeek.com/2011/05/tinymce-styles-dropdown-wordpress-visual-editor/)

Don't Forget to read [Configuration:style_formats](http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/Configuration%3astyle_formats)

Comment: ya I did ..but can,t get the advance toolbar.

Comment: @JewelSarkar Check the update to see whether it can help u

Comment: ya Thankz... @7-isnotbad